# Create JSON Patch 6902 from two yaml/json files

Tags: json, yaml

Imagine I have a file foo.yaml and a modified version of this file called foo2.yaml.

Is there a way to create a correspondig [json patch 6902](https://jsonpatch.com/)?

Answer (score 3):

The same was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547709/generate-json-patch-from-two-objects

For example:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/rfc6902
- https://github.com/Starcounter-Jack/JSON-Patch (`compare` method)